# Looking for the name of a formula

Tags: probability, transformation, density-function

Probability subject. The question is:

If fx(x)=xe^(-x^2/2) for x>0 and Y=lnX find the density function for Y

The solution is:(e)^(2y-1/2e^2y)

I'm stuck on the part of the solution that uses this formula:

fy(y)=fx(v(y)) times |v'(y)|

Thanks to anyone who's willing to help.

Comment: Go easy people, first posting....

Comment: @xcv I´v made an edit of your question. Have a look if it is right.

Comment: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/book/export/html/157

Comment: Does this have to do with random variables, I wonder? I seem to recall a formula somewhere with the absolute value of a derivative when transforming distribution functions.

Comment: @xcv put dollar signs around it to to translate it... should give you this if you do that $(F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(u(X)\leq y)=P(X\leq v(y))=\int_{c_1}^{v(y)} f(x)dx)$

Comment: Please do not "remove" your question that way.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Randomgirl is correct. Translating the bad formatting from the link:

"Let X be a continuous random variable with generic probability density function $f(x)$ defined over the support $c_1 < x < c_2$. And, let $Y = u(X)$ be an invertible function of X with inverse function $X = v(Y)$.

Then, using the change-of-variable technique, the probability density function of Y is:

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(v(y)) |v'(y)|$$

defined over the support $u(c_1) < y < u(c_2)$. "